# How can I make content disappear when a user logs in?

Tags: php, css, authentication, wordpress

I am working in Wordpress, and I would like to make certain elements on my navigation bar disappear once a user logs in. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you create a separate menu?

Comment: will you provide me the site link again ?

Comment: https://hughesjobs.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the plugin code and also understand the how the plugin works but you do it in another way a quite tricky but it works.

```
add_filter('wp_head','my_js_code');

function my_js_code()
{
  if (is_user_logged_in()) 
  {
 ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">


     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(".sfsi_widget").remove();   
</script>


 <?php
      } 
    }
```

Write this code in functions.php and see if it works

What I have done basically checks if user is logged in if yes performs  javascript to remove that div of social plugin. 
if it will not work you have to

- see if this javascript loaded in document  or not via analyzing source code of generated page
- check browser console for errors
  **Best Of Luck**

Comment: the code does work, but everytime the page reloads , the social icons still appears for a split second , then it disappears

Comment: try by removing window.onload function and just putting the inner content of the function directly i.e. var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(".sfsi_widget").remove()

Comment: where shall i place this code? And remove what... and where ... im sorry i dont know much on php

Comment: Deleting the window load function did now work?.... unless I deleted it the wrong way... ??

Comment: check out new code in functions.php you can remove given old code

Comment: i erased the code you gave me previously from my functions.php file... and replaced it with the new one above.... no action took place.... they didnt disappear at all

Comment: will you provide me dummy login

Comment: username: employertest    password: coner09

Comment: that is for my website

Comment: username: testrun1 password: corner09

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to check if a user is logged in.

So if you put your html inside this code, it will disappear as soon as your user logs in:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
   // your html, only for not logged users
}
```

Comment: where do I place this code.... and how exactly. I am using a plug in , the social icons at the top of the page. How can I make those disappear? https://hughesjobs.net

Comment: You have to edit the php file containing your menu and use this code.

Comment: I have login to your website i cannot see the social icons there really?